# GETH Error on personal_sendTransaction/eth_sendTransaction

Tags: blockchain

[image]

Been trying to use personal_sendTransaction / eth_sendTransaction for days but I cannot get pass this error. I have tried different combination of gas/gasprice/value but I cannot make it work.

PS. My Go ETH Server is fully synced

Last combination I tried:

```
"gas":"0x51DAC207A000" // 90000000000000 Wei
"gasPrice":"0x218711A00" // 9000000000 Wei
"value":"0x38D7EA4C68000" // 1000000000000000 Wei
```

Answer (score 1):

First "gas" is an integer number without unit, it is not measured in "wei".

In mainnet the actual block gas limit is 8M, rinkeby is around 7.5M and ropsten around 8M (ropsten sometimes fluctuates wildly from 4.7M to 20M).

To transfer ether between external owned accounts (not contracts) then a gas limit of 21000 should be enough.

To interact with a contract it is better to estimate the gas previously to have an idea, you can use the function `estimateGas`.

To deploy a really simple contract 1M should be sufficient, typical contracts are around 4M to 6M gas. Transaction for ERC20 Token transfer are below 250K gas.

Comment: gas is no unit? so just a hexadecimal of 21000 which is 0x5208? how about gasPrice and value? Should they be in gwei, wei or ether?

Comment: "Gas" is only a number without unit, for transfer between "normal" accounts is 21k. "GasPrice" and "value" at low level are expressed "wei", at high level a wallet will convert them to a more convenient unit.